# Update table in Polymorphic Relation in laravel

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am working with laravel5.4. I have used Polymorphic relation for image upload.

So I have created table as images.

image table :

[image]

In image model I have created function for relation that looks like below.

Image model :

```
public function imageInfo()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

In ticket model I have created function like below

Ticket model :

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Image\Image', 'imageInfo');
}
```

In ticket controller for storing image I have create functionality like :

```
if($request->file('file') != "")
{
    $createPath = public_path('images/upload/ticket');

    if(!File::exists($createPath.'/'.$ticket->id))
    {
        File::makeDirectory($createPath.'/'.$ticket->id,0775,true);
    }

    $destination_path = public_path('images/upload/ticket/'.$ticket->id);

    $files = $request->file('file');

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $image = new Image;
        $image->name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->type = $file->getClientMimeType();
        if($ticket_info->images()->save($image))
        {
            $file->move($destination_path,$file->getClientOriginalName());
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfect for storing image in database. But I want to update this table so according to ticket_id.

So how can I update this table using sync() method or any other option?

Comment: What information would you want to update?

Comment: @RossWilson I want to update **name** and **type** in `images` table. In this table imageInfo_id is the ticket_id from ticket table and imageInfo_type is the class name of ticket. When change image from ticket than **images** will automatically updated.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar hi have you figured this out yet? In a same problem

Comment: @maxit Yes, but did not use sync() method. If you have any idea using sync() method than let me know.

Comment: I figured it out too, but without using sync, it's not possible with sync in this case

Comment: @maxit ok thank you.

Comment: How did you solve the problem guys?